# Adding up demand and subtracting that from total stock based on demand date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssms, reportbuilder3.0

[image]

I need to be able to subtract each days demand from supply to give me a figure based on the demand each day, see image

i need to be able to say the stock level on 06/03/14 is 7169 (stock) - minus the demand for that date 3157 = 4012

on 18/03/14  i need to be able to add togther the demand from 06/03/14 & 18/03/14 and subtract that from the stock number (7169)- (3157+2632) =  1380 so that for each date i am adding up the reqiured figure plus the figures previously and subtracting that from the stock

would it be best to perform this in report builder or in sql, below is my script (where ALLCOMPREQD is required & BINST is my stock level and WORDSTAT is my date

```
SELECT dbo.mbf010.wordno,
       dbo.mbf010.partno_wor,
       dbo.mbb010.description AS [WO Description],
       dbo.mbf020.partno_f02com,
       MBB010_1.description   AS [Part Description],
       dbo.mbf020.allcompreqd,
       dbo.mbf010.wordstart,
       dbo.mbc010.binst
FROM   dbo.mbf010
       INNER JOIN dbo.mbf020
               ON dbo.mbf010.account15_wor = dbo.mbf020.account15_f02par
                  AND dbo.mbf010.wordno = dbo.mbf020.wordno_f02par
                  AND dbo.mbf010.wordnosuf = dbo.mbf020.wordnosuf_f02par
                  AND dbo.mbf010.procstage_wor = dbo.mbf020.procstage_f02par
       INNER JOIN dbo.mbb010
               ON dbo.mbf010.partno_wor = dbo.mbb010.partno
                  AND dbo.mbf010.account15_wor = dbo.mbb010.account15
       INNER JOIN dbo.mbb010 AS MBB010_1
               ON dbo.mbf020.account15_f02par = MBB010_1.account15
                  AND dbo.mbf020.partno_f02com = MBB010_1.partno
       INNER JOIN dbo.mbc010
               ON dbo.mbf020.account15_f02par = dbo.mbc010.account15_inv
                  AND dbo.mbf020.partno_f02com = dbo.mbc010.partno_inv
WHERE  ( dbo.mbf020.partno_f02com = '04LEF009' )
       AND ( dbo.mbf020.allcompreqd > 0 )
```

Comment: How are you calculating Demand? For instance, I'm not seeing how March 6th and March 18th are related to one another. Also, you need to try to capture the interest of people who might answer, and that script may be scaring them off. Format your code to make it easy for someone unfamiliar with your script to understand.

Comment: Can you post the results of the query? It's not clear from just looking at the code - does "binst" give you the stock level on the date ("wordstart"), or is it the *current* stock level when the query executes (in which case the report only makes sense if those demand dates are in the future)?

Comment: thanks for your help guys - ive used the Running Value expression in Reporting Services to achieve what i need